# detect swipe left/right in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I´m trying to detect swipe left-right but I´m having a problem for example if a user makes a swipe up or down and a little bit to one of the sides it detects it as a swipe left (for example)

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
        initialClientX: 0,
        finalClientX: 0,
    }
}

handleTouchStart(event) {
    this.setState({
        initialClientX: event.nativeEvent.touches[0].clientX
    });
}

handleTouchMove(event) {
    this.setState({
        finalClientX: event.nativeEvent.touches[0].clientX
    });
}

handleTouchEnd() {
    if (this.state.finalClientX < this.state.initialClientX) {
        console.log('swipe left')
    }

    this.setState({
        initialClientX: 0,
        finalClientX: 0
    });
}
```

how can I make this not too sensitive? should I also keep track of clientY?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up checking also for **clientY** as well a threshold

```
if ((this.state.finalClientX > this.state.initialClientX)
    && (this.state.finalClientY - this.state.initialClientY < 10)) {
        console.log('swipe left')
}
```